# Finding $\mathcal{L}^{-1}_t\left(\frac{e^{|x|\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}}}}{\sqrt{ks}}\right)$ Using the General Inversion Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, residue-calculus

I am trying to classify the singularities in the function $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}_t\left(\frac{e^{|x|\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}}}}{\sqrt{ks}}\right), \ k>0$$ as the final part of solving a PDE.
To use the General Inversion Formula,
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi I}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty} e^{st}F(s) \ ds,$$ for $t\geq 0$, I need to calculate the residues of $$F(s)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}_t\left(\frac{e^{|x|\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}}}}{\sqrt{ks}}\right).$$
I think the only singular point is when $s=0$. Is this a simple pole?

I considered the equation $g(s)=\sqrt{ks}$. I used the definition below:

> $z_0$ is a zero of order $k$ for $f(z)$ if and only if $f(z_0)=f'(z_0)=...=f^{k-1}(z_0)=0$ and $f^k(z_0)\neq 0$.

However, $g'(0)\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: If you take the principal value of the square root, the argument of $\sqrt s$ tends to $\pm \pi/4$ on the line $s = \gamma + i \sigma$. The absolute value of $\exp(\sqrt s)$ grows as $\exp(\sqrt{\sigma/2})$, the Bromwich integral diverges.

Answer (score 1):

There is no deleted neighborhood of $s=0$ in which the function is defined and analytic. so we cannot talk about the type of singularity at $0$.

Comment: Are there any singular points of $f$?

Comment: $f$ is a two-valued function. You have to fix a branch of the square root first before you can analyze this function.

Comment: I am trying to find $\mathcal{L}^{-1}_t(f(s))$ as part of solving a PDE. I was hoping to use the general inversion formula, which relies on the Residue theorem. In $f(s)$, $k>0$ (constant).